# same code, but acts differently on store site

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

The slideshows for http://vbwpublishing.com and http://store.virtualbookworm.com should have the exact same code, and work the same way. But on the store, only the background color can be seen and no images are visible. The links still work though... Can anyone figure out if there is something I can change to fix this on the store?

Thanks y'all are the best!

Comment: Post your code; People are more likely to help when you post the relevant code as opposed to having them go out to your site and scour it themselves.

Comment: I can't find any broken images...

Comment: Every thumbnail, the arrow and the background images all return 404 errors.  You code may be fine but your image paths are obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs to the images are incorrect. You have:

http://store.virtualbookworm.com/images/slideimage1.jpg

But it should be something else, perhaps "http://vbwpublishing.com/images/slideimage1.jpg"? (If the background really are identical).

Answer (score 0):

Images are not found.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://store.virtualbookworm.com/assets/templates/v32029/css/images/slidearrow.png
...